# The `lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created` is not present in Symfony's profiler

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I've added this listener

```
acme_api.event.jwt_created_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created, method: onJWTCreated }
```

but the event is not dispatched (is not visible) from symfony's profiler. I am trying to use it to customize the token expiration time. The method `onJWTCreated` is not called!

Comment: Your service configuration is good, the problem isn't here. Did you try to clear the cache ?

Comment: Yes. Cache cleared. The event does not appear.

Comment: How do you use the bundle? Are you using the built-in guard authenticator? Do you have something in your logs regarding this event?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your previous question [Why my jwt tokens never expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914601/why-my-jwt-tokens-never-expire/46024171#46024171), you are not using the bundle through the Symfony security system (config), but deliver tokens "manually" using low level APIs from your controller.

The JWTCreatedEvent is dispatched by JWTManager ('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager` service). If you want the event to be dispatched, consider using that service instead of using the encoder directly (which may become private in the next major, thus not accessible from a controller unless injected).